# 450 Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: vba

I have a macro that uses Tiny Term Emulator and connects to the session and enters user ID and password to login. I am having issues because for some reason its not loading the defualt keyboard and it fails on the line below and when I check my dbug spreadsheet in my vBA macro it gives the error of Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. The line thats bolded is where the macro fails. Can someone please review and assist

```
Public Sub ShellExecuteTinyTerm(Optional ByVal iForeGround As Integer = 1, _
                                Optional ByVal iBackGround As Integer = 8)
'Declarations
Dim lKeyBoard As Long
Dim lErr As Long, sErr As String
Const sSource As String = "ShellExecuteTinyTerm()"

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
StackTrace msModule, sSource
    'Call Trap(msModule & " " & sSource, "This proc/func has been trapped")
'Code Start:

If (iBackGround < 0) Or (iBackGround > 8) Then
    Err.Raise MDEBUG_Framework.glHANDLED_ERROR, msModule & " " & sSource, ""
End If

If Not gFrmTE.teIBS.IsConnected Then
    With gFrmTE.teIBS
        .Node = msHOST_NAME
        .NetPort = miTELNET_PORT
        '
        .ConnectionType = miTELNET_CONNECTION
        .Emulation = 18
        .AutoLogin = miAUTOLOGIN_OFF
        .DuplexMode = 0
        **lKeyBoard = .LoadKeyboard("C:\\Program Files\\Century\\TinyTERM\\keyboard.dat", "Default.keyboard")**
        '
        .WindowsLookandFeel = True
        'Basic
        .SetFGColor 0, iForeGround
        .SetBGColor 0, iBackGround
        'Reverse
        .SetFGColor 1, iForeGround
        .SetBGColor 1, iBackGround
        'Underlined.
        .SetFGColor 3, iForeGround
        .SetBGColor 3, iBackGround

        .RevDim (1)

        'Cursor
        .CursorType = 0
        .SetFGColor 2, iForeGround
        .SetBGColor 2, iBackGround
        .SetFGColor 5, iForeGround
        .SetBGColor 5, iBackGround
        
        .DestructiveBackspace = False
        .connect
    End With
End If

If gFrmTE.Visible = False Then
    gFrmTE.Show vbModeless
End If
Set MGEN_Globals.gTTEScreen = gFrmTE.teIBS

Finished:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    lErr = Err.Number
    sErr = Err.Description
    If gbDebug_Mode Then
        DebugPrint msModule & " " & sSource, lErr & "  " & sErr
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
'Error Cleanup
        DebugPrint msModule & " " & sSource, lErr & " " & sErr
        Err.Raise lErr, msModule & " " & sSource, sErr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked that `teIBS.LoadKeyboard()`, whatever that is, accepts two arguments?

Comment: yeah but isnt that what these are  the path is the first argument and the file name is the second argument? right?

.LoadKeyboard("C:\\Program Files\\Century\\TinyTERM\\keyboard.dat", "Default.keyboard")

Comment: This is the arguments that you are providing. Have you verified that `.LoadKeyboard()`, whatever it is, expects to receive two arguments?

Comment: Hello, this is what it shows in the documentation

Boolean LoadKeyboard(sKeyFile,sLayout)
Load keyboard layout sLayout from the .dat file specified by sKeyFile.
te.LoadKeyboard(“keyboard.dat”,”English”)

Comment: Can you see that in the object browser? Where does it take you if you put the caret on the word LoadKeyboard and press Shift+F2?

Comment: Its showing
Function LoadKeyboard (pszFilename as string, pszScheme as String)